# Unable to show hidden span

Tags: jquery, html

I want to show hidden span when button is click.
My html looks like:

```
<ul>
    <li>
         <span  class="sfFormlabel" style="display:none" >show</span>
        <div id="div1">
          <input type="button" value="show" class="show">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
         <span  class="sfFormlabel" style="display:none" >show1</span>
        <div id="div2">
          <input type="button" value="show" class="show">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and jquery:

```
$('.show').live("click", function () {
    alert('test');
$(this).parent('li').children('span').show();
});
```

But I am fail to show hidden span.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shree/b43V7/1/)

Comment: I found a solution like this.Is this a correct way to do this.http://jsfiddle.net/shree/b43V7/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.parents` or `.closest` instead of `.parent`.

```
$(this).parents('li').children('span').show();
```

Or

```
$(this).closest('li').children('span').show();
```

***PS:*** `.live` is is deprecated, use `.on` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#about").css("background-color","#222222");  

    $('.show').live("click", function () {
    alert('test');
$('.sfFormlabel').show();
});

});
```

Comment: But if u only want one of them to show, go with xdazz answer, unless u give them ids.